# I cannot reference a class - issues somewhere

Tags: java, javax

Since I am fairly new to Java, I only know enough to make variables, import stuff and some other stuff; but what I do not get is why the begin() function is not running and any help that can explain whats going on and possibly rewrite it in a better way would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jerry

```
package nEW;

// Not Working - trying to format start by making a new "begin" object when run.

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Renderer;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.print.*;

public class Chessstart
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        open.start();
    }
        static class open
        {



            // All packages imported , ready for use... Add more if need be : +

            public class begin implements ActionListener, KeyListener
            {
                public boolean board_show =true;
                public int AOB1 = 16;
                public int AOB2 = 16;

                public static final int WOB = 640;
                public static final int HOB = 640;

                public int GStat = 0;
                // Defines when game is playing, toggle-able twice 0, 1, 2
                // 0 = Menu, 1 = Paused, 2 = Game
                // Might Become Redundant
                // TODO Make this feature redundant!


                public boolean click, space;
                public int turn;
                public Component renderer;


                public void ScreenUp()
                {
                    Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);
                    JFrame jframe = new JFrame("CHESS");

                    jframe.setSize(WOB, HOB);
                    jframe.setVisible(true);

                    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    jframe.add(renderer);
                    jframe.addKeyListener(this);



                    timer.start();


                }

                public void render(Graphics g)
                {
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.fillRect(0, 0, WOB, HOB);
                    if (GStat == 0 || GStat == 1 || GStat == 2)
                    {
                        if (GStat == 0)
                        {
                            System.out.print("GStat return 0 - Render running");
                        }
                        if (GStat == 1)
                        {
                            System.out.print("GStat return 1 - render running");
                        }
                        if (GStat == 2)
                        {
                            System.out.print("GStat return 2 - render running");
                        }
                    }
                }






                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0){
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }


        }

            public static void start() {
                open.begin();

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: `begin` is **not** a method , it's an inner _class_ of `open`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am fairly new too when it comes to Interfaces in Java, but...

Just like Ousmane Mahy Diaw mentionned in his comment, begin is a class, not a function. That is basic Java knowledge, so first I would recommend practicing doing your chess with command line. An Interface should be a separate effort.

There is a lot of problems with that code. I recommend using Netbeans IDE. It could help you out when it comes to basic errors.

I recommend doing like so when it comes to building Interfaces with JFrames:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Renderer;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.print.*;

public class Chessstart extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
    public boolean board_show =true;
    public int AOB1 = 16;
    public int AOB2 = 16;

    public static final int WOB = 640;
    public static final int HOB = 640;

    public int GStat = 0;
    // Defines when game is playing, toggle-able twice 0, 1, 2
    // 0 = Menu, 1 = Paused, 2 = Game
    // Might Become Redundant
    // TODO Make this feature redundant!


    public boolean click, space;
    public int turn;
    public Component renderer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chessstart ch = new Chessstart();
        //ch.render(ch.getGraphics());
        ch.screenUp();
    }

    public void screenUp()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("CHESS");

        jframe.setSize(WOB, HOB);
        jframe.setVisible(true);

        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.add(renderer);
        jframe.addKeyListener(this);

        timer.start();
    }

    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WOB, HOB);
        if (GStat == 0 || GStat == 1 || GStat == 2)
        {
            if (GStat == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("GStat return 0 - Render running");
            }
            if (GStat == 1)
            {
                System.out.print("GStat return 1 - render running");
            }
            if (GStat == 2)
            {
                System.out.print("GStat return 2 - render running");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

This at least opens up your window, but please do note that you require initializing an object before using one. Meaning that rendering will not succeed without initialized graphics.

Also, why even use Renderer? You do not need to, the windows shows up and no errors like so:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Renderer;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.print.*;

public class Chessstart extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
    public boolean board_show =true;
    public int AOB1 = 16;
    public int AOB2 = 16;

    public static final int WOB = 640;
    public static final int HOB = 640;

    public int GStat = 0;
    // Defines when game is playing, toggle-able twice 0, 1, 2
    // 0 = Menu, 1 = Paused, 2 = Game
    // Might Become Redundant
    // TODO Make this feature redundant!


    public boolean click, space;
    public int turn;
    public Component renderer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chessstart ch = new Chessstart();
        //ch.render(ch.getGraphics());
        ch.screenUp();
    }

    public void screenUp()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("CHESS");

        jframe.setSize(WOB, HOB);
        jframe.setVisible(true);

        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jframe.addKeyListener(this);

        timer.start();
    }

    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WOB, HOB);
        if (GStat == 0 || GStat == 1 || GStat == 2)
        {
            if (GStat == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("GStat return 0 - Render running");
            }
            if (GStat == 1)
            {
                System.out.print("GStat return 1 - render running");
            }
            if (GStat == 2)
            {
                System.out.print("GStat return 2 - render running");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

Comment: thankyou! I was stuck on that stage for hours.... I just didnt know where I went wrong! Thanks... Obviously I missed a few lessons eh?

Comment: ecept, I noticed that I am getting errors at lines 39 and 51, and unknown errors elsewhere...

Comment: No problem, I just edited the answer. Why do you use Renderer? Works just fine without it.

Comment: all fine now, forgot to see the last bit u added

Comment: Because I was following another game that I was making, with the help of a tutorial

Comment: Read the other text besides copying the code. It might help ;)

Comment: now... how to I add the details and files and etc.. to make it a proper chess game...

Comment: How do I use the Render Class to do the graphics if I cannot call it without it asking me for a parameter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142950/discussion-between-artur-and-jerryplayz101).